# iOS -> setNavigationBarHidden delay

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, delay

When i use

```
[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
```

and in another view

```
[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
```

I can clearly see a delay when navigation bar is 'disappearing' and 'appearing' between these views. Is there any way to omit this and force navigation bar to appear/disappear immediately after switching views?

Eg.
From class A to B- I can firstly see view, then navigation bar is appearing after +/- 1s.
From class B to A- I can see view with navigation bar and after about 1s bar is disappearing.

Comment: If there's many animation at the same time, it's normal that it doesn't look fluid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could setup the navigation bar after the new view has completed its transition onto the screen.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated;
{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO 
                                             animated:animated];
}
```

Comment: It seems there is no better method atm. I can see white space when i dismiss this bar in this case, but still looks better. Thanks for this solution.